# Controlling whether a nested form builds or edits based on attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a form for a model `Case` that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` another model, `Side`. For the edit form, I want to build new `Sides` if the case doesn't have any, and edit the sides the `Case` has if they exist.

The issue right now is that even when I'm trying to edit the existing sides, it just ends up creating new ones.

Here's my view:

```
<%= form_for @case do |f| %>

. . .

  <div id="sides">
    <%= f.fields_for :sides do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :name, "Side Name" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  . . .

<% end %>
```

And my controller:

```
def edit
  @case = Case.find(params[:id])
  2.times { @case.sides.build } unless @case.sides.present?
end

def update
  @case = Case.find(params[:id])
  if @case.update_attributes(case_params)
    flash[:success] = "Case updated"
    redirect_to @case
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

. . .

def case_params
  params[:opp_choice] = params[:opp_choice] == '1'
  params.require(:case).permit(:link,       :case_statement,
                               :title,      :opp_choice,
                               :topic_list, sides_attributes: [:name])
end
```

let me know if there's any other info you need

Comment: `@case.sides` should be `@case.sides.present?` If you have the relationships set up as I think you do, `@case.sides` should return `[]` at minimum, which is a truthy value. Thus you will always be building.

Comment: It should, I updated my file and the post. I'm still having the same problem, though.